# Возможности в графических оболочках Linux

Tags: linux, debian

В Linux есть возможность перетаскивать иконки так, чтобы они анимационно тянулись, как резина. Подскажите, как это реализовать, какие утилиты для этого необходимы?

Comment: У вас какое DE стоит?

Comment: Ну , у меня Mate

Comment: попробуйте ``apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager``, но сначала установите GNOME (что самом по себе не является хорошей идеей, поскольку GNOME - это многожрущее DE)

Comment: Так, а где то, что мне нужно?

Comment: **compizconfig-settings-manager** я установил

Comment: "Так, а где то, что мне нужно?" - Давайте, мы не будем из одного вопроса вытягивать кучу других, и при том, делая это в комментариях. Если у вас появился вопрос "Где то, что мне нужно?", то будьте любезны оформить новый вопрос. И при чем, **оформить, как надо**.

Comment: Без проблем :) Мне необходима утилита , поддерживающая возможность перетаскивать иконки так, чтобы они анимационно тянулись, как резина.

Comment: Такая же возможность есть еще на macOS

Comment: задайте новый вопрос. Укажите в нём, какое ДЕ у вас, какая система, чего хотите добиться, что скачали, что не нашли, и вам дадут развернутый ответ.

Comment: **сначала установите GNOME** - это зачем?! TS сказал, что дистрибутив унего - mate. А это:  среда рабочего стола, являющаяся ответвлением от кодовой базы неподдерживаемой в настоящее время среды GNOME 2.

Другое дело, что я не уверен, что в во втором гноме такое вообще есть.

Если Вам очень сильно нужны "кружавчики", то ставьте любой дистрибутив, в котором основным ДМ является KDE.  В его плазмоидах есть такое, о чём даже думать страшно, так что ваши "резинки" наверняка есть.

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto, что за бюрократия! Друзья, у человека был конкретный вопрос, а вы какие-то совсем нерелевантные советы даёте :/